# Save temporary .jpg file to computer

Tags: java, file, svg, jpeg

There is a method in java called `.createTempFile` that I used for a method that generates a picture and returns the File. This is a part of the code:

```
File jpgFile = File.createTempFile("tmp, ".jpg");
//fill the file with information ...
return jpgFile;
```

When I access the method in my main-method I get a File. Now my quesiton is: how can I save this file? I try to do this:

```
File f = generateJPG(); // (the method that is explained above)
File out = new File("C:/fileJPG.jpg");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(out, true);
BufferedWriter outw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

String aLine = null;
while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outw.write(aLine);
    outw.newLine();
}

in.close();
outw.close();
```

But this won't work and just gives me a very confusing picture filled with random pixels. So how can I save this temporary file to my computer?

Comment: use `ImageIO` and `BufferedImage`

Comment: Can you actually see an image at any point in time? Its very possible the image data you create is not correct and creates a garbage file.

Comment: @RobertLongson well the first code just explains how TempFiles are created if someone has forgotton / does not know about it. It jsut should explain that I have a method that generates an image as an TempFile and that I want to access it in the next piece of code (to save it to my computer)

Comment: @PaulSwetz I can see an image, it just looks very weird (green / white /red sections) and I don't think its generated the wrong way. My program does this: generate a .svg File, transcode it into .jpg and return it. And I have tested it by generating the .svg File and writing the .jpg directly to my desktop with the transcoder. Now I just wrote the infomation into a TempFile, so I don't know what could go wrong.

Comment: Can you post the image output? It may be helpful. I would guess if you get 'almost' what you expect that something bad is happening during the transcode process, maybe compression issues. Or are you saying you can open the jpeg on the desktop and its fine?

Comment: @JordiCastilla This worked, thank you very much. (code in my answer)

Comment: Yeah, FileWriter is for text based writing. Use FileOutputStream for binary files. Or ImageIO, BufferedImage, as suggested.

Comment: @JetStream glad to help, I looked at question and see it was easy to fix, so I preferred to guide you. Really happy you succeeded and more because you learned something new ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. I used `ImageIO` and `BufferedImage`, just like [@JordiCastilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850595/jordi-castilla) said and it worked fine. Here is the code:

```
File f = generateJPG();

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);

File out = new File("C:/fileJPG.jpg");

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", out);
```